# How can I setup a read/write device that spawns a program?

Tags: linux, shell, devices, fifo

I don't know if this is possible but I had no idea how to research this concept. Is it possible and if how do I...

create a device file (i.e. `/dev/remoteclip`) that will, when written to or read from, spawn a program or shell script?

The use case would be in sharing text to a remote clipboard. For example saw I have a Mac to the side of my Linux box. As it stands I can do the following to share content:

```
$ ssh macbox "pbcopy" < myFile
$ ssh macbox "pbpaste" > myFile
```

I am wondering if it is possible to have a device or FIFO on the linux filesystem that when you write to it it would execute the ssh command:

```
$ cat myFile >> /dev/macbook-clipboard
$ cat /dev/macbook-clipboard > myFile
```

That way editors and other programs can simply write to a device / FIFO.

This is more of a learning exercise on if this is possible and if so how. It is not a need and likely the merits of this is purely academic then useful in typical workflows.

Comment: This looks like a job for FUSE. Hopefully someone will be able to post an answer detailing how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this. It requires creating a background process that continues to read from the FIFO. For example:

```
$ mkfifo hopper
$ while :; do ssh macbox "pbcopy"; done < hopper &
$ cat myFile >> hopper
```

(Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41046119/227176))

Now I don't fully understand this but I'm willing to guess that having the `< hopper` on the surrounding while loop blocks the loop which is why the CPU doesn't appear to fry an egg and when no data is being funneled into the FIFO there isn't a stray SSH session sitting around.

I'm quite impressed with how thoughtful and forward thinking all these *Unix tools are. I honestly do not understand why this is taught in school or why modern software development is all about reinventing these age old wheels. Amazing!

---

To end the above process use `kill %1`.